# Get sessions active for more 3 hours

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have query to see active sessions:

```
select pid as process_id, 
       usename as username, 
       datname as database_name, 
       client_addr as client_address, 
       application_name,
       backend_start,
       state,
       state_change
from pg_stat_activity;
```

How to get sessions that have been active for more than 3 hours?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT pid AS process_id,
       usename AS username,
       datname AS database_name,
       client_addr AS client_address,
       application_name,
       backend_start,
       state,
       state_change
FROM   pg_stat_activity
WHERE  backend_start < now() - interval '3 hours';  -- just add this
```

Comment: Hmm. I think it is unclear what is meant with "sessions that are active". It could also mean "sessions that have been in `state = 'active'` for the last three hours".

Comment: That would make it a question worth asking.